# relationships and nested data eloquent and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

In my app a user can have many listing, and many listings can have many tags. On one of my pages, I am doing the following query to get a users listings based on their profile slug,

`$user = User::with('listings.tags', 'listings.assets')->where('slug', $slug)->first();`

From this result set I am wanting to get all the listings and pluck unique name and assign that to a new key i.e usedTags.

However when I do this,

```
return $user->filter(function($listings){
            foreach($listings as $listing) {
                return $listing;
                $user['tags'][] = $l->tags->pluck('tag');
            }
        });
```

I get the following error,

> message: "Call to undefined method App\User::filter()"

So I am assuming that as I using `first()` it does not return a collection(?) so I cannot filter over it, so what can I do here?

Comment: `$user->listings->filter(...)`

Comment: You should also be able to use a sub query in with(), with([‘relation’ => function($q) {}); you can probably filter tags like that, by applying distinct or group. I.e. $q->select(‘name’)->groupBy(‘name’)